Power BI MySQL Database Connector Error After Installing MySQL .NET Connector
I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using Power BI, but I keep encountering an issue. When I try to connect, it redirects me to MySQL Connector/NET download page. I have installed the MySQL Connector/NET (latest version) and restarted my machine, but I still receive the following error:
MySQL database

This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Downloaded and installed the MySQL Connector/NET from the official MySQL website.
Restarted my computer after installation.
Verified that the MySQL service is running and that I can connect to the database using other tools (e.g., MySQL Workbench).
Despite these steps, Power BI does not recognize the connector.
Additional Information:
Power BI version: 2.128.1380.0 64-bit (April 2024)
MySQL Connector/NET version: 8.4.0
MySQL Server version: 5.7.44-48
Operating System: Windows 11 Business

I solved this by downloading a historic version of the connector - mysql-connector-net-8.0.26

I solved this by downloading a historic version of the connector  MySQL connector-net-8.0.26 This is the best version and I have downloaded many of the version and there are some issues with the MySQL Connector/NET.
